# Opening A Searchable With A button Android

Tags: java, android, search

Hey guys,
I'm trying to open a Searchable (searchmanager) but with a ImageButton so that people can use it even if their device has no physical search button. How could I proceed in doing this.

Thanks,
Arber

Answer (score 1):

"Your application can also activate the search dialog on demand by calling 
[onSearchRequested](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSearchRequested%28%29)".